# Gradle Kotlin script: "Include" - None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: gradle, kotlin

IntelIJ IDEA 2018.3 
Gradle 5.1.

In my Kotlin script

build.gradle.kts

```
build.gradle.kts


plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.20"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "4.0.3"
    id("com.devsoap.vaadin-flow") version "1.0"
    id("org.gretty") version "2.3.1"
}

val kotlinVersion = "1.3.20" //by extra("1.3.20")
val jettyVersion = "9.4.14.v20181114"
val vaadinVersion = "12.0.4"

dependencies {
    //  Plugins
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:4.0.3")
    //
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion")
    //  Vaadin
    implementation("com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:$vaadinVersion")
    implementation("com.vaadin:vaadin-core:$vaadinVersion")
}

val shadowJar by tasks.getting(ShadowJar::class) {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.myproject.Main" 

    mergeServiceFiles()

    include("frontend/*/*.*") // error here
}
```

But I get error in IntelIJ IDEA:

[image]

Comment: Works in Gradle 5.2.1 and IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 BETA with Kotlin 1.3.21. The `include` function should resolve to the `CopySpec` interface, that is implemented by the `ShadowJar` class.

you may also check if you do not miss a closing bracket from a junit task definition block

Comment: After upgrade to Gradle 5.2.1 - now I get error:  Cannot choose between com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:13.0.1 variant compile and com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:13.0.1 variant enforced-platform-compile because they provide the same capability: com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:13.0.1 . I updated my post

Comment: Try killing all Gradle processes and doing a clean start. Does it work from the console?

Comment: I delete folder "build" and then: gradlew clean assemble. But I get same error: Cannot choose between com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:13.0.1 variant compile and com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:13.0.1 ...