# Kotlin scripts: "Include" - None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: gradle, kotlin, vaadin

Gradle 5.1.1
Vaadin 12.0.4
InteliJ IDEA 2018.3

In my Kotlin script

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.20"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "4.0.3"
    id("com.devsoap.vaadin-flow") version "1.0"
    id("org.gretty") version "2.3.1"
}

val kotlinVersion = "1.3.20" //by extra("1.3.20")
val jettyVersion = "9.4.14.v20181"

val shadowJar by tasks.getting(ShadowJar::class) {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.myproject.Main"

    mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

I create executable jar by Gradle's pluggin: shadowjar.

```
gradlew shadowjar
```

And it success createд executable jar.

Nice.

Now I want to add external folder "**frontend**" with all subfolders to executable jar.
So I try this:

```
val shadowJar by tasks.getting(ShadowJar::class) {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.myproject.Main"

    mergeServiceFiles()
    include("frontend/*/*.*") // error here
}
```

But I get error in InteliJ IDEA:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144723/gradle-kotlin-script-include-none-of-the-following-functions-can-be-called#comment97031864_55144723

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Kotlin script: "Include" - None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144723/gradle-kotlin-script-include-none-of-the-following-functions-can-be-called)

Comment: I tried with gradle 5.2.1, idea 2018.3 and it seems to work. Can you please try to run the task using the command line and see if it works?

Comment: I start (Gradle 5.1.1) in command line: gradlew shadowjar. It's success build. But the result size of jar is very little (301 bytes). But it must be (in my project) about 50 MB

Comment: Maybe you can check your filter provided in the include(), but the error you pasted seems to be due to some caching in your ide as gradle seems to work fine on command line. You can check if you have any import on the top of the file which can resolve to a different include